# Flot chart panning boundaries

Tags: jquery, flot

I am looking for a way to restrict the panning of a flot chart before the min plot point and max plot point of the graph.  I.e. if there are no points after the latest visible one then do not continue to pan.

Does anyone know an option without me having to hack the navigate.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The navigate plugin provides a panRange option that should do what you want.  See the header of [jquery.flot.navigate.js](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/jquery.flot.navigate.js) for more info.

Comment: Do you have any example code as I have tried to set the pan range to the minimum date and maximum date - pan: {

            interactive: false,
            panRange: [new Date(options["GraphMinXValue"]),  new Date(options["GraphMaxXValue"])]
        }

Comment: No, there aren't any built-in examples demonstrating panRange.  The reason why your example doesn't work is because panRange is supposed to be expressed numerically, i.e. the original timestamps, not JavaScript Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

This will stop it panning into the future:

```
xaxis: {panRange: [null, new Date()]},
```